# IPMItool SET User Role

Tags: php, linux, webui, ipmitool

I've a problem with the user access. I would like to add an OPERATOR priv to an user, but I've got a probleme :

The request  :

```
ipmitool channel setaccess 1 3 link=on ipmi=on callin=on privilege=3
```

change only the priv of IPMI LAN Privilege to Operator, and not the USER ROLE

How can I set both to Operator ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Users are defined by channel, and they have the access that's defined for the channel itself. The [IPMI spec](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/product-briefs/ipmi-second-gen-interface-spec-v2-rev1-1.pdf) calls this out in '1.7.26 Channel Model, Authentication, Sessions, and Users', where it mentions that users are defined in terms of being over a session-based model, and as such have their privileges defined in those terms, and as the only way to define 'sessionable' users is by allocating them to a channel, their role is defined in terms of the channel, rather than in terms of the role itself.

> Session-based channels thus have at least one user ‘login’ and support user and message authentication. Session-less channels do not have users or authentication. LAN and serial/modem channels are examples of session-based, while the System Interface and IPMB are examples of session-less channels.